# Change default category/tag "All"

Tags: wordpress

I designed a homepage for a friend in wordpress: [www.milana-fotografie.com](http://www.milana-fotografie.com). I have a problem with default category/tag "All" (all frontpage gallery pictures are linked to this tag). I want to change it to German language or put other word for it. But i didnt found how to do this in Wordpress.

I tried to find some translator plugins, but didn't found a good solution so far.

So thank you in advance for any advices how i can solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

From your dashboard, go to Posts > Categories and look at the panel showing your categories.  Edit the one named "All" and change its display name to what you need.

Comment: Pity, but it doesn't work. If I go to Posts. I see only 3 categories: Galllery (here all  the photos are compiled), uncetogerized and home-video. If I change the name of "Gallery" category, it still not remove "All" tag from the frontpage.